# maven-war-plugin chmod exit code was:127

Tags: maven, chmod, maven-war-plugin

I am running a shell to call a ant, which further call a maven in Redhat.

Could anyone point out the context of this error?

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:wa
>   r (default-war) on project sites: Error unpacking file
>   [/scratch/mingtzha/12.1/.../sites-dojo/target/sites-dojo-1.6.1-12.1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.war]to
>   [/scratch
>   /mingtzha/12.1/.../sites-dojo]: chmod exit code was: 127 -> [Help 1]

I found this "useJvmChmod" property maybe relevant.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html

Comment: Running from command line directly or via Jenkins (or something simlilar)?

Comment: @khmarbaise, running in command line by calling a shell script will invoke ant then maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is resolved. I had a silly mistake in Shell script. I wrote :PATH instead of :$PATH, it actually breaks all command line calls such as "chmod".