# Jenkins build issue

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I got the following error while running a Jenkins job

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project mosm-ui: Error unpacking file [/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/cisco/xmp/wap/xmpweb/2.0.5/xmpweb-2.0.5.war]to [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MOS_2.3/workspace/target/war/work/com.cisco.xmp.wap/xmpweb]: chmod exit code was: 127 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project mosm-ui: Error unpacking file [/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/cisco/xmp/wap/xmpweb/2.0.5/xmpweb-2.0.5.war]to [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MOS_2.3/workspace/target/war/work/com.cisco.xmp.wap/xmpweb]

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error unpacking file [/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/cisco/xmp/wap/xmpweb/2.0.5/xmpweb-2.0.5.war]to [/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MOS_2.3/workspace/target/war/work/com.cisco.xmp.wap/xmpweb]

The size of the xmpweb-2.0.5.war file is 209MB.

JDK - 1.7.0_55 , Maven version - 3.2.1.
OS - RHEL 6.4

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Is there enough disk space? Does the jenkins user have appropriate permissions?

Comment: Yes it has enough space and the user has the full permission.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be passing your PATH variable correctly.  Look for something that looks like `:PATH` and make it `:$PATH`

see [this similar issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19365798/302139) and stop thinking of it as a maven failure, but rather a bad call to chmod.

Comment: No i am passing the PATH variable corectly.

Comment: Must be some other issue then